# Javascript - Best practice on using If Else in this example

Tags: javascript, if-statement, coding-style

I'm currently learning Javascript and working through a rock, scissors, paper tutorial. There's already a couple of queries on this site based on the same tutorial at Codeacademy. However, my query is based on my perspective and so I would appreciate some feedback from the SO community.

My code is as follows:-

```js
var userChoice = prompt("Are you picking rock, paper or scissors?");
var computerChoice = Math.random();
if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
    computerChoice = "rock";
} else if(computerChoice <= 0.67) {
    computerChoice = "paper";
} else {
    computerChoice = "scissors";
}

console.log ("Computer picks" + " " +computerChoice);
var compare = function (choice1, choice2) {
    if (choice1 === choice2) {
        console.log ("You're both psychic. It's a tie!");
    }    


    if (choice1=="rock") {
        if (choice2 =="scissors") {
            console.log ("Rock wins. You bad boy, you.");
        }
        if (choice2=="paper") {
         console.log ("Paper wins. You noob") ;
        }
    }

    if (choice1=="paper") {
        if (choice2=="rock") {
            console.log ("Paper wins. You bad boy, you.");
        }
        if (choice2=="scissors") {
            console.log ("Scissors wins. You noob.") ;
        }
    }

    if (choice1=="scissors") {
        if (choice2=="rock") {
            console.log ("Rock wins, you noob");
            }
        if (choice2=="paper") {
            console.log ("Scissors wins. You bad boy, you.");
        }
    }

    };

    compare (userChoice,computerChoice);
```

I've always thought that when using conditionals, it should only be either of the below cases:

1. single condition, then just `if`'s are fine.
2. more than one condition, then it must be *`if` and end with an `else`* OR *`if` , `else if` etc and end with an `else`.*

As a result, I initially used an `else` in the second nested, conditional statement here `if (choice2=="paper")` . Then realised the logic was wrong because it printed that string as well, if it was a tie.

So I thought about it and realised it would work if I used an `if` instead of the else. And it does work. However, I am just not sure if my code is just wrong...or less than ideal. Is it?

Additionally, to make it look better (and not just full of `if`'s) I was thinking about swapping out the `if` in `if (choice1=="paper")` with an `else if`. However, I wouldn't know how to end the next condition - `if (choice1=="scissors") {` . How would you do it?

Pardon the long queries - I'm just trying to make sure I understand it well.

Thanks

Comment: You don't have to end with an `else`. `if` and `else if` and nothing else is just fine.

Comment: I see. And is this quite common, if the situation deserves it?

Comment: Yes, it's perfectly normal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is completely code style, so you should strive for 'clean code'.

The most naive alternative would be to use a switch. For example:

```
var compare = function (choice1, choice2) {

    switch(true){
        case choice1 === choice2:
            console.log ("You're both psychic. It's a tie!");
            break;
        case choice1 ===  "rock":
            if(choice2 === "scissors"){
                console.log ("Rock wins. You bad boy, you.");
            } else{
                console.log ("Paper wins. You noob") ;
            }
            break;
        case choice1 === "paper":
                if (choice2=="rock") {
                    console.log ("Paper wins. You bad boy, you.");
                } else{
                    console.log ("Scissors wins. You noob.") ;
                }
            break;
        case choice1 === "scissors":
            if (choice2=="rock") {
                console.log ("Rock wins, you noob");
            } else{
                console.log ("Scissors wins. You bad boy, you.");
            }
            break;
    }
};
```

That's just one method though. Whatever you choose, you should try to make the code cleaner and more elegant.

This version might look better:

```
var compare = function(choice1, choice2){
    var options = ['rock','paper','scissors'];
    var result = options.indexOf(choice1) - options.indexOf(choice2);
    switch(result){
        case 1:
        case -2:
            //choice1 wins
            break;
        case 0: 
            //tie
            break;
        case -1:
        case 2:
            //choice2 wins
            break;
    }
}
```

But this version is not so immediately understood - so there's a solution which is better than both this and the first one- a solution which is cleaner and is much easier for the reader to understand - you should try to find one.

Comment: Nice `switch` solution in option 2. I had something similar, but you beat me to it!

Comment: Thanks! I was wondering about `case` usage in JS but I haven't learnt the syntax yet. I do have another question though. Most other examples for this same tutorial use `return` instead of `console.log`. I understand `return` is for returning a value when used in a function, e.g. equation of some calculation. But in this case, we are simple printing out a string.  In this particular exercise, wouldn't it be wrong to use `return` instead of using something that just prints out, e.g `console.log` ?

Comment: I'm personally not a big fan of mixing `switch` statements with `if...else` construct. However, your second solution is a nice take on the problem.

Comment: @kravoon it's incorrect to use console.log in most scenarios. 
The best code is modular, reusable code.
You really should think about the purpose of the problem and try to 'separate the concerns'. 

In other words, your code is doing 2 things:
1) determining a winner for rock-paper-scissors game
2) logging to console the result

It's actually more correct to use a function that will return the result of the winner, and based on that using another function to log the result to console.

This way, if tomorrow you were to decide to display an alert instead, it's easier to change the code.

Comment: of course, my above explanation isn't necessarily relevant for this specific case - but it is more of a 'best practice' and really the correct way to think about writing code in general.

Comment: @Etai you're right. My understand was to run the function to determine the outcome of the game, return a value in such a way that could be used for a popup or something interactive etc AND console.log is purely for me - debugging purposes. That's really what console.log is for, right? In this case, since I currently have limited knowledge of what statements to use to return values, I am using console.log only, just to make sure that my code works the way I expect it to..

Answer (score 1):

Definitely use else if, so that the second condition test only runs if the first was false

```
if ('hi' === 'hi) {
    console.log('true');
} else{
    console.log('this will never log')
}
```

Can also be written with a Ternary operator:

```
'hi' === 'hi' ? console.log('true') : console.log('this will never log');
```

Alternative ternary option --

`console.log('hi' === 'hi' ? 'true' : 'this will never log');`

Answer (score 0):

```
if(choice1 == choice2){
    console.log ("You're both psychic. It's a tie!");
}
if(choice1 == "rock"){
    if(choice2 == "scissors"){
        console.log ("Rock wins. You bad boy, you.");
    }
    else {
        console.log ("Paper wins. You noob") ;
    }
}
...
```

Assuming `choice1` and `choice2` are both `"rock"`, the function checks `if(choice1 == choice2)`. This is true, so it prints the 'tie' message.

Because the next conditional is also an if, it then checks if `choice1` is `"rock"`. It is, so it enters the nested block, checks if `choice2` is "scissors" - it's not, so it moves to the `else` block, and prints the 'paper wins' message.

When it is a tie, `choice1 == choice2` you don't really need to check anything further. `else if` and `else` conditionals are only checked if the conditions before are not satisfied.

So you could change it to:

```
if(choice1 == choice2){
    console.log ("You're both psychic. It's a tie!");
}
else if(choice1 == "rock"){
    if(choice2 == "scissors"){
        console.log ("Rock wins. You bad boy, you.");
    }
    else {
        console.log ("Paper wins. You noob") ;
    }
}
else if(choice1 == "paper"){
    ...
}
else{ //choice1 == "scissors"
    ...
}
```

You can also break out of functions early using a `return` statements. Or, as [Etai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1544003/etai) suggests, you could use `switch` to check the conditions.

Comment: Thanks. Your first example is exactly what I did initially. The problem with that is that the `else` block also prints out if `choice2` was a rock. Your second example seems to overcome this and is easy to read, for me. Would upvote if I could but I'm new to this site :P

Comment: Wait, are you saying that if I used `return` instead of `console.log` in  `if(choice1 == choice2) { console.log ....` , it would stop the other statements from running, thus avoiding the problem above?   But I thought `return` is meant to be used when returning a value that was obtained from a function being carried out. And that is not the case here since we are only printing out a string response?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer. The idea would be to have the `compare` function return a string, which you would then log to the console. So you would have `if(choice1 == choice2){ return "You're both psychic. It's a tie!"; }`, etc. And then, instead of just calling the function, you would log it to the console: `console.log(compare(userChoice,computerChoice));`